# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. Changing it to 11 or above has no effect

Tags: android, android-studio

This question is fairly old on Stackoverflow but none of the provided solutions worked for me.
So I try to generate an Android App Bundle with Android Studio and first receive the message

`Generate Signed Bundle: Errors while building Bundle file. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.`

which results in

`Cause: argument type mismatch`

Then in the terminal I run

`./gradlew build --warning-mode all`

which gives me:

[image]

So I tried various things:

1. Android Studio (Arctic Fox) => Preferences => Build/Execution/Deployment => Buidl Tools => Gradle => set Version to 11.0.10

[image]

I also tried Version 17. No success. Still the same error on building

2. I reset Android Studio to default settings. After restart there was a popup asking me to change SDK from 1.8 - I clicked there and did the change. No success. Still the same error.
3. I run ./gradlew --version  in Terminal and receive this

[image]

So basically everything I do regarding changing the SDK has no effect. Honestly I am out of options now and don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, your gradle project still uses JDK 1.8. There can be two solutions:-

1. Add this to your `gradle.properties` file:
   `org.gradle.java.home=path/to/jdk/11+`
2. Ensure that your `gradle.properties` file doesn't have a java home declaration and then, append the path of JDK 11 `bin` folder to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd option ;)

Answer (score 1):

On MAC, this worked for me

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
```